# Burninate the [material] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

We have a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material) whose description says:

> THIS TAG IS AMBIGUOUS. Not to be confused with [material-design].

Do we need it? I'd say burninate it. Questions tagged with [material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material) are either not belonging to that tag, or were intended for [material-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material-design).

Comment: This tag is im[material].

Comment: "THIS TAG IS AMBIGUOUS" is a pretty silly description. Most people aren't going to care. You might have a prayer of a second thought if it said "DO NOT USE THIS TAG".

Comment: @CodyGray I have the feeling that most people that tag with [tag:material] don't go to the tag page :)

Comment: Well, it shows up in the excerpt. But you're probably right that they don't even read that.

Comment: Will this still be considered? There's close to 1000 questions tagged with this tag. I've gone through the questions tagged with [tag:material] and retagged them.

Comment: I've successfully cleaned up the remaining questions tagged with this tag and it has since been removed.

Comment: Niceee, @Edric !